# How to sort lines with >> double angle brackets?

Tags: sort

It seems that `sort` behaves strangely on lines such as `>>b`

```
$ cat test
a
>>b
b
c
>
>>

$ sort test
>
>>
a
b
>>b
c
```

I would expect the `>>b` line to be the third line output by `sort` but it is the fifth. Why does it do this and is there a way to make `sort` give my expected output?

I'm using GNU/Linux Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorting algorithms in modern locales are quite complex.

Each character (actually *collating element* which could consist of a sequence of several characters like the Czech `ch`) is given a number of *collating weights* that decide of their sorting order.

When comparing two strings, the first weight of all the characters is used first, and other weights are used later to decide ties if the two strings sorted the same with the first weights.

For instance, in many locales, `e`, `é` and `E` have the same *primary* weight (they are of the same equivalence class, they all match `[=e=]`).

So, when comparing for instance `echo`, `été` and `Enter`, in the first pass, `e`, `é` and `E` having the same primary weight, it's the second character that will determine the order (`c` before `n` before `t`).

When comparing `été`, `Été`, `Ete`, after the first pass, they all sort the same, so we use the second pass using the secondary weight. In typical GNU locales, the second weight for latin script characters is used to prioritise accents (no accent comes first, then acute, grave, breve, circumflex...). We'll then need to use the third weight to decide between `été` and `Été` and that will be based on case (lowercase first in most locales). There are even characters that end up sorting the same because all their weights are identical.

That is used to sort text in a similar way as dictionaries do, as a human would do.

In a dictionary, you'll find that space and most punctuation characters are also ignored. For instance `de facto` sorts in between `debut` and `devoid`. The first weight of the space character is IGNORE.

On a GNU system, you'll find the core collating rules defined in the `/usr/share/i18n/locales/iso14651_t1_common` (the path may vary with the distribution). In there, you'll see:

```
ifdef UPPERCASE_FIRST
<CAP>
else
<MIN>
endif
[...]
ifdef UPPERCASE_FIRST
[...]
<MIN> # 10
[...]
else
[...]
<CAP> # 9
[...]
endif

[...]
order_start <SPECIAL>;forward;backward;forward;forward,position
<U0020> IGNORE;IGNORE;IGNORE;<U0020> # 32 <SP>
[...]
<U003E> IGNORE;IGNORE;IGNORE;<h> # 140 >
[...]
ifdef DIACRIT_FORWARD
order_start <LATIN>;forward;forward;forward;forward,position
else
order_start <LATIN>;forward;backward;forward;forward,position
endif
[...]
<U0065> <e>;<BAS>;<MIN>;IGNORE # 259 e
<U00E9> <e>;<ACA>;<MIN>;IGNORE # 260 é
[...]
<U0045> <e>;<BAS>;<CAP>;IGNORE # 577 E
<U00C9> <e>;<ACA>;<CAP>;IGNORE # 578 É
```

Which illustrate what we've just said. Both space and `>` have their first 3 weights set to `IGNORE`. It's only for strings sorting the same for the first 3 weights that their relative order will be considered (`>` before space as that `<h>` would list before the unspecified collating symbol `<U0020>`).

In locales that define `UPPERCASE_FIRST` (like `/usr/share/i18n/locales/tr_TR`), upper case letters will come first (in the 3<sup>rd</sup> pass). Same with `DIACRIT_FORWARD` where some locales like `de_DE` can decide to reverse the order of diacritics for the 2<sup>nd</sup> pass.

`>` and  `>>` sort the same in the 1<sup>st</sup>, 2<sup>nd</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> pass. In the 4<sup>th</sup>, `>` sorts before `>>` as the empty string sorts before everything.

`>>b` sorts after `b` because they sort the same in the first 3 passes, but in the fourth pass, `b` is IGNORE, so `>` is greater. It's less than `c` in the first pass (`>` ignored, and `b` before `c`)... You get the idea.

Now, if you look at the `C` locale definition. It's a lot simpler. There's only one weight, and the weight is based on the codepoint value from U+0000 to U+10FFFF. So `SPC` (U+0020) sorts before `>` (U+003E), which sorts before `b` (U+0062) which sorts before `c` (U+0063). No character is ever ignored.

Note that with the GNU libc at least, that order defined in the C locale definition file is ignored when it comes to comparison functions (`strcoll()` and co. as used by `sort`). Regardless of the value of `LC_CTYPE`, with `LC_COLLATE=C`, `strcoll()` is equivalent to `strcmp()`. As in the comparison is always on the byte value, even if those bytes correspond to characters whose unicode codepoint sort the other way round (like 0xA4 U+20AC EURO SIGN vs A5 U+00A5 YEN SIGN in the ISO-8859-15 charset), so `LC_ALL=C sort` and `LC_COLLATE=C sort` (provided `LC_ALL` is not otherwise set) will have the same effect there.

Answer (score 1):

From the `sort(1)` man page:

```
   *** WARNING *** The locale specified by the  environment  affects  sort  order.   Set
   LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses native byte values.
```

So to sort by byte value, use:

```
LC_ALL=C sort test
```

Otherwise, `sort` will ignore the leading characters until it comes across a key it can sort by, which is why `>>b` and `b` end up adjacent to each other.